# Finding out if a sequence is martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I have a sequence of sequences defined as:

$$Y[k] = \alpha \prod_{n=1}^kX[k]$$

Which I want to find an $\alpha$ for which it is martingale. I have that

$$E[Y[k] \mid X[0],\dots,X[k-1]] = Y[k-1]$$

this can in turn be

$$E\left[\alpha \prod_{n=1}^kX[k] \mid X[0],\dots,X[k-1]\right] = ? $$

But I am stuck here and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Any help is welcome.

edit: you know that X is iid and is a random sequence with outcomes in $R^+$. $\alpha$ is a constant.

edit: Maybe you can see that:
$$Y[k-1] = \alpha \prod_{n=1}^{k-1}X[k]$$

Comment: Instead of writing \space | \space, you can write \mid.  Then the spacing is there automatically.  (I changed it.) (And I changed some other details including \left[ and \right], for sizes of brackets, and \dots and "display" as opposed to "inline" format.)

Comment: What do you know about the $X[i]$? Is $\alpha$ supposed to be a constant, or another random variable? Suppose you set $\alpha = 0$, then won't this be a martingale?

Comment: However, if you set alpha to zero, wont this be the trivial case?

Comment: You probably want to find $\alpha$ such that $Y_n=\alpha^nX_1X_2\cdots X_n$ is a martingale, not $Y_n=\alpha X_1X_2\cdots X_n$. (Unrelated: the notation $X[n]$ instead of $X_n$ produces ugly formulas when these include lots of them.)

Comment: The text specify $Y_n=\alpha \prod Xn$

Comment: @larstoc: That seems likely to be a typo in the text.  A constant multiple of a martingale is another martingale, so as written the value of $\alpha$ won't have any effect on whether you get a martingale or not (unless $\alpha = 0$).  Can you post or cite an excerpt of the text where this appears?

Comment: That makes sense, as we found that it is martingale independent of $\alpha$. However, the book errata does not state this as a fault. I will bring it up, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $Y_{n+1}=X_{n+1}Y_n$ and $Y_n$ is $\sigma(X_j,0\leqslant j\leqslant n)=:\mathcal F_n$ measurable, hence $$\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\mid \sigma(X_j,0\leqslant j\leqslant n)]=Y_n\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid \sigma(X_j,0\leqslant j\leqslant n)].$$
By independence, $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid \sigma(X_j,0\leqslant j\leqslant n)]=\mathbb E[X_{n+1}]$, hence we need $\mathbb E[X_1]=1$.

With the version: "find $a$ such that $\left(Y_n:=a^n\prod_{j=1}^nX_j,\mathcal F_n\right)$ is a martingale", we have $\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n]=a\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}]Y_n$, 
so we want $a\mathbb E[Y_{1}]=1$.